# Loading text data in an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I have created an iPhone application, I would like to be able to load in a batch of data with the application, but to not store all of the data in the .h or.m files.

Is there a way to attach a text file as a resource in the application, and then load that text file into an NSString in the iPhone application.

I am looking to include this text data file as part of the iPhone application when it is complied, but to access the data at run time.

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, it's easy. Just add your .txt files to your project (drag them to the Files tree). To access them, you need to first get the path:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"filename" ofType: @"txt"];
```

Then load the string:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *fileData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
```

Comment: Just realized the link I provided uses the deprecated method, oops!  So +1 for being current!

Comment: Perfect.  That did exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example doing exactly that:
http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/data-management/how-to-read-a-file-from-your-application-bundle

Relevant code from above link:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"important" ofType:@"txt"];  
if (filePath) {  
  NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
  if (myText) {  
    textView.text= myText;  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Be sure to see my comment on @Ben Gottlieb's answer, I will leave my answer here because I think the link is still helpful, but you will need to use @Ben Gottlieb's version of the stringWithContentsOfFile method when using the latest version of the SDK.